# I'm having trouble accessing data through javascript fetch request

Tags: javascript, json, request, response, fetch

So here's my problem, I'm having trouble fetching data from a url then displaying that data via a list on my page.

Here's the url Im drawing from:

http://ign-apis.herokuapp.com/articles

I would to get access to the third property, "data"

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Articles</h1>
<ul id = "articles"></ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const ign_ul = document.getElementById('articles');
const ign_url = 'http://ign-apis.herokuapp.com/articles?startIndex=30\u0026count=5';

fetch(ign_url)
 .then(function(response) { 
   return response.json();
})
 .then(function(json) {  
    let articles = json.data;
    return articles.map(function(article) {
      let li = createNode('li'),
          img = createNode('img'),
          span = createNode('span');
      img.src = article.thumbnails[0].url; //dont think this is right...
      span.innerHTML = `${article.metadata.headline}`;
      append(li, img);
      append(li, span);
      append(ign_ul, li);
    })
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

It keeps logging the error "[object Error] {}"
No data is displayed

I took the same approach to this url:

https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10

using

```
let articles = json.results;
```

and I was able to fetch the info just fine

I'm a newbie when it comes to fetch, get, post, etc.
I'm thinking it might be that the url data isnt formatted properly to be successfully converted to json.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

[EDIT]

Here's the error I'm getting

Fetch API cannot load http://ign-apis.herokuapp.com/articles?startIndex=30&count=5. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: `It keeps logging the error "[object Error] {}" No data is displayed` - try using `console.error(error)` - to get a stack trace to see where the error occurs

Comment: `//dont think this is right...` - looks OK based on the response

Comment: however `${data.metadata.headline}` looks wrong ... you have no var called `data` - that should be `${article.metadata.headline}` - or just `span.innerHTML = article.metadata.headline;`

Comment: Of course, if the request is cross-origin, nothing will help you make this work - check your browser developer tools console for any messages regarding CORS or cross origin requests

Comment: It's working for me, try opening the "ign_url" in a new tab and then run the following snippet extracted from your code:                                                       const ign_ul = document.getElementById('articles');
const ign_url = 'http://ign-apis.herokuapp.com/articles?startIndex=30\u0026count=5';

fetch(ign_url)
 .then(function(response) { 
   return response.json();
})
 .then(function(json) {  
    let articles = json.data;
    console.log(json.data.length)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

Comment: It prints the length of your data array as 5

Comment: @AnupamSaini - running that code in your comment in the console of `http://ign-apis.herokuapp.com/articles?startIndex=30\u0026count=5` will of course avoid CORS issues (at least in Chrome, Firefox wont let you do that at all) - I'm surprised the OP claims the error is not more descriptive, as every browser I've tried clearly points out that there is a CORS issue

Comment: @JaromandaX - Yes agreed there would be a cors issue, just wanted to  help him/her pinpoint the root cause, provided everything else is setup fine. For instance try running the snippet on a new tab.

Comment: I understand - the error in the code is using `data.metadata.headline` instead of `article.metadata.headline` - however, that is never going to be called, since the underlying CORS issue - that needs to be dealt with **first**

Comment: @ Jaromanda X Yah I edited the code a bit while writing here and that was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: And in case this might be the problem, here is the initial url that was given, it has different properties
http://ign-apis.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Ok. so when I use
`$.ajax({ url: ign_url, dataType: "jsonp", jsonpCallback: "logResults" });`
with logResults just doing console.log(json) it successfully returns the data. Temporary workaround I guess. 
So pertaining to CORS, when using fetch and xmlhttprequest theres the same origin policy to deal with. If the server you are drawing from but dont have access to change/edit does not have, for this instance, a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, are you just boned? or is there a way to make it work?